# algebraically dependent and transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $T$ be transcendental basis of $R$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $A\subset T.$ Consider $$S=\{a^{-1}\colon a\in A\}$$ **1** Is S algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$ ?

My second question: If $B\subset\mathbb R\setminus A$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$ and $B\not\subset T.$ So, $T\cup B$ is algebraically dependent. What can we say about the relation between of elements  of $B$ and $T$? Is it true in general $B\subset \mathbb Q\cdot T$?

Comment: What do you mean by “$\Bbb Q\cdot T$” ?. Are you just referring to the $\Bbb Q$-linear span of $T$?

Comment: @Lubin I meant jut $\mathbb Q \times T$,  that is, $\mathbb Q\cdot T=\{qt\colon q\in \mathbb  Q,\  t\in T\}$

Comment: This is very similar to [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370275/elements-in-transcendental-basis) and your [deleted version which appeared on MSE yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805398/inverse-elements-of-algebraically-independent-set). Asking 3 questions about the same thing across 2 sites in ~21 hours is a little fast and a little much - MSE/MO aren't designed to provide instant help.

Answer (score 1):

The second question is the less interesting: No, it is not likely at all that $B\subset\Bbb Q\cdot T$ That would be a supremely exceptional occurrence.

For the more interesting first question, the answer is Yes. Indeed, suppose there’s a $\Bbb Q$-algebraic relation among finitely many (say $m$) of the elements of $S$. Call these $\{s_1,\cdots,s_m\}$. (We now have $t_i=1/s_i\in A\subset T$.) This algebraic relation would be a polynomial $f(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ with rational coefficients, that became zero when each $s_i$  is substituted for $X_i$. Now let $N$ be any integer larger than every one of the exponents on the variables of $f$, and multiply the now-known relation
$f(\frac1{t_1},\cdots,\frac1{t_m})=0$, thus giving
$$
t_1^Nt_2^N\cdots t_m^Nf\left(\frac1{t_1},\cdots,\frac1{t_m}\right)=0,
$$
and this is a relation of algebraic dependence among elements of $T$, which our hypothesis on $T$ forbids.

Comment: Thank you vert much. One thing to be clear. multiplication of finite number  algebraically indepednet is still algebraically independent. Right?

Comment: You mean a single rational number times each of them? Yes. Or do you mean different rational numbers multiplying each of them? Again yes. I think you need to study and meditate on the definition of algebraic independence of a set of numbers.

Comment: If you know a books or lectures that have good information about these topics algebraically independent and transcendental basis, please let me know